# Webcam not working on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: usb, webcam

I recently bought the cheapest infrared webcam I could find on the internet. It works fine on my Windows machine, however I can't get it to work on my Ubuntu 18.10. Can you please help?

What I've tried already:

- opening Cheese says "No device found"
- opening VLC, going to **Media > Open Capture Device** and trying to use `/dev/video0` or `/dev/video1` (I don't know why I get 2 of those when connecting the camera) says:

  > Your input can't be opened:
  > VLC is unable to open the MRL 'v4l2:///dev/video0'. Check the log for details."

  And here's the log:

  ```
  main debug: nothing to play
  main debug: processing request item: v4l2:///dev/video1, node: Playlist, skip: 0
  main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
  main debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index 0
  main debug: starting playback of new item
  main debug: resyncing on v4l2:///dev/video1
  main debug: v4l2:///dev/video1 is at 0
  main debug: creating new input thread
  main debug: Creating an input for 'v4l2:///dev/video1'
  main debug: requesting art for new input thread
  main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
  main debug: using default timeshift path
  main debug: `v4l2:///dev/video1' gives access `v4l2' demux `any' path `/dev/video1'
  main debug: creating demux: access='v4l2' demux='any' location='/dev/video1' file='/dev/video1'
  main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "v4l2": 21 candidates
  v4l2 debug: opening device '/dev/video1'
  v4l2 error: cannot open device '/dev/video1': Operation not permitted
  v4l2 debug: opening device '/dev/video1'
  main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
  lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/master/snap/vlc/770/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
  lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /snap/vlc/770/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
  lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /snap/vlc/770/usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
  main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
  main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
  lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/master/snap/vlc/770/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
  lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /snap/vlc/770/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art
  v4l2 error: cannot open device '/dev/video1': Operation not permitted
  main debug: no access_demux modules matched
  main debug: creating access: v4l2:///dev/video1
  main debug:  (path: /dev/video1)
  main debug: looking for access module matching "v4l2": 26 candidates
  v4l2 debug: opening device '/dev/video1'
  v4l2 error: cannot open device '/dev/video1': Operation not permitted
  main debug: no access modules matched
  lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /snap/vlc/770/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
  main debug: dead input
  main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
  main debug: nothing to play
  ```
- when running `lsusb -t`, I get:

  ```
  /:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
  /:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
       |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
           |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
           |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
  /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
       |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
           |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
           |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
           |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M 
  /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
       |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
           |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
           |__ Port 2: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
               |__ Port 4: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
                   |__ Port 4: Dev 13, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
                   |__ Port 4: Dev 13, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 12M
                   |__ Port 4: Dev 13, If 4, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 12M
                   |__ Port 4: Dev 13, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
                   |__ Port 4: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 12M
  ```

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Not from me, unfortunately. I basically gave up soon after asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

I opened up synaptic (I recommend installing it) and looked up the VLC extensions. At first I thought I had to install vlc-plugin-zvbi but this is not available, at least no in 20.04.

I got it working with the following:
sudo apt install vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization

To be fair I didn't check to see if it worked with less packages. I just clicked all the multimedia options.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but this solves nothing. The problem being the webcam not detected system wide it doesn't matter which VLC plugins are or aren't installed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1202846)